# TF10158: The user or group name XXXXX contains unsupported characters, is empty, or too long

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, tfsbuild

QueryShelvedChanges() method is throwing exception shown below,

TF10158: The user or group name XXXXX contains unsupported characters, is empty, or too long.

Could anyone please help what can be the reason ?

Comment: Are you building an application or extension that calls `QueryShelvedChanges`?  Can you show the code?  Can you show the actual arguments to the call?

Comment: Can you upload your project in one drive (at least provide the arguments you used)?

Comment: Passing "shelveset" in argument QueryShelvedChanges(shelveset)... The strange part is we have multiple domain users, for type_1 users its working fine but Type_2 users are facing problem with the mentioned error.

Comment: Can you show more detailed code?

Answer (score 0):

QueryShelvedChanges() method has a variant where it takes a shelveset name and shelveset owner name as parameters as described [Here in Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb138981%28v%3Dvs.120%29).

The error which you have mentioned could happen if the owner's display name has spaces contained in them. Display names in AD usually will have spaces due to 'LastName, FirstName' format.

Use the **'User logon name'** from the **Account** tab of the user in Active Directory as in this ***screenshot*** below, for the *'shelveset owner'* property of the method QueryShelvedChanges().

[image]